# Fastest / most efficient way to combine heterogeneous csv files in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have 1000 csv files with size varying from 8MB to 17MB. Each file has a portion of 6 metrics. Examples are below:

```
File1 (columns): key, metric1, metric2, metric3
File1 (values):  k1, m1, m2, m3
File2 (columns): key, metric4, metric5, metric6
File2 (values):  k1, m4, m5, m6
File3 (columns): key, metric2, metric4, metric5, metric6
File3 (values):  k2, m2, m4, m5, m6
```

All methods I tried today combined files into the output below:

```
Output (columns): key, metric1, metric2, metric3, metric4, metric5, metric6
Output (values):  key1, m1,   m2,   m3,   null, null, null
                  key1, null, null, null, m4,   m5,   m6
                  key2, null, m2,   null, m4,   m5,   m6
```

What I really need is also consolidate rows by key column:

```
Output (columns): key, metric1, metric2, metric3, metric4, metric5, metric6
Output (values):  key1, m1,   m2, m3,   m4, m5, m6
                  key2, null, m2, null, m4, m5, m6
```

I know `pandas` could do it; however, it may take forever to finish 1000 files.

Comment: Can you share your approach?

Comment: Are you trying to combine all 1000 csv files into one csv file?

Comment: @quamrana, yes, I want to combine them all into 1 file.

Comment: @Aaron I don't have solution yet.

Comment: 1000 * 8MB = 8GB so memory is limited. Maybe it is a good idea to construct an embedded database and query all records. For example, SQLite?

Comment: Your excel file is going to be way too large... I would take Aaron's suggestion and put everything into a database.

Comment: I would like to run the combination process in python due to various reasons. I am running on a server that has 256GB memory.

Comment: If you have only one row and at most six columns in each file, how are they 6 MB let alone 17 MB? Are the metrics a composite data structure?

Comment: @Acccumulation I just list one row of values as example.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what your format is, but I think this will work:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(expected_metrics)
 for filename in filelist:
       current_data = pd.read_csv(filename,index_col = 'key')
       current_columns = current_data.columns
       current_row = current_data.index[0] 
       df.loc[current_row,current_columns] = current_data
```

Notes:

-This requires you know ahead of time what metrics will be present so you can initialize `expected_metrics`. You could instead replace the last line with:

```
 for column in current_columns:
      df.loc[current_row,column] = current_data[column]
```

This would probably take longer

-If a particular (key, metric) combination shows up more than once, only the last one will be recorded.

-The result will have `key` as the index. If you want it as a data column, you'll have to do `df['key'] = df.index`.

I wouldn't expect this to take "forever"; a thousand files should take at worst a few minutes unless you have a very large number of metrics.

You could also do:

```
 data = {}
 for filename in filelist:
       current_data = pd.read_csv(filename,index_col = 'key')
       current_columns = current_data.columns
       current_row = current_data.index[0] 
       data[current_row] = {column:list(current_data[column])[0] for column in current_columns}
```

This will give a dictionary where each key is a key from your data, and the value is a dictionary representing the row for that key.

EDIT:
A third option would be to take the output you already have and do `df.groupby(by='key').max()` This will create a dataframe where each entry is the maximum metric for all the rows with the same key. So, again, if you have only one value for each (key,metric) combination, this should give you what you want. If you have more than one value, all but the largest will be ignored.

Comment: Do you have any ideas other than using pandas? Based on my experience of pandas, it might take a couple hours to finish.

Comment: Other than the basic file reading interface, I haven't worked with parsers other than pandas'.